# pg_dump in 1G VPS crashes

Tags: postgresql, backup

I'm trying to run pg_dump on a relatively small database (2G), but pg_dump keeps crashing with an out of memory error.

```
du -h --max-depth=0 9.4
1.9G    9.4
```

The command:

```
pg_dump -Fp -h "$HOSTNAME" -U "$USERNAME" "$DATABASE" | gzip > $FINAL_BACKUP_DIR"$DATABASE".sql.gz.in_progress;
```

Any ideas on how to allow the dump to happen?

```
****  Edit *****
-bash-4.2$ pg_dump -t new_answers -F tar -b -f new_answers.dump mydatabase
out of memory
```

the new_answers table has a TEXT column, but all the objects in are < 1k.  Also,there is only about 300 rows.  "dmesg | grep OOM" turned up nothing.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using the built-in compressed format offered by pg_dump.  I would think that would save memory since sql files are huge.   So something like: `pg_dump -Fc -h "$HOSTNAME" -U "$USERNAME" -f mydb.backup "$DATABASE"`

Comment: @LR1234567 A pipeline doesn't buffer the whole lot in memory, and `pg_dump` outputs the SQL in a stream without buffering tables, etc. It should not consume much RAM, and the pipeline to gzip shouldn't make a meaningful difference.

Comment: Are you certain it's `pg_dump`, not the PostgreSQL backend it's connected to, that's OOMing? When you say it "Crashes with an out-of-memory error" what is the *exact text* of the error? Copy and paste it into an edit to your question please. Also check the PostgreSQL server logs. Finally, is VM overcommit enabled on your VPS? Check `dmesg`, see if there are any messages from the "OOM killer" there (just "dmesg | grep OOM")

Comment: See edits above - even a small table with a binary column causes the crash

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? I recall there have been some fixes for pg_dump memory/time consumption recently.

Comment: This is on Postgresl 9.4, most recent 9.4 build as of a week ago.